# Why is my Java program for the Caesar cipher returning empty Strings?

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

I am trying to create a program that can implement the Caesar cipher to an input String. The code can compile, however, when I tested it, it always returns an empty string shown as "". I don't know how to fix this problem. I desperately need some suggestions. Thank you very much. I have edited it with the answer I have received so far, but the problem still exists. Here is my code.:

```
public static String caesarCipher (String cipher, int shiftAmount) {
    
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (int index = 0; index < cipher.length; index = index + 1 ){
      
      char letter = cipher.charAt(index);
      
      if (Character.isUpperCase(letter)){
        letter = (char)(((int) letter - 'A' + shiftAmount) % 26 + 'A');
      }
      else if (Character.isLowerCase(letter)){
        letter = (char)(((int) letter - 'a' + shiftAmount) % 26 + 'a');
      }
      else if (Character.isDigit(letter)){
        letter = letter + shiftAmount;
      }
      
      str.append(letter);
    }
    
    return str.toString();
  }
```

Here was what I did in the interaction and the returned result:

```
> HW2.caesarCipher("Character", 1)
""
```

What I am trying to do is to let it returns "Dibsbdufs".

Comment: Can you like put your error message in your question also? LIke the output , screenshot maybe?

Comment: Maybe you can check this out: https://cpluspluscaeserciphertechnique.blogspot.com/2018/02/caeser-cipher-encryption-technique.html 
This isn't in java though but the methodology used here may help you in one way if it does.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Please post your actual working code.

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/MVb0c1

Comment: You need to learn to debug your own code.  Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Debugging is skill the you learn by practicing it.  Remember that the goal of homework is not to get marks.  It is to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems incorrect. In order to shift characters by some amount, you need to get there ASCII code and add the shift amount to it.

```
char x = ((int) 'A' - 65 + 3) % 26 + 65;
```

Here I am getting ASCII value of A by type casting it by integer and then substracting by 65 (ASCII of 'A')  and then add the shift value to it. If the shifting needs to be done only in alphabets then you need to wrap around the values by doing mod 26. Because if I find the shifted value of 'Z' by 3 then I will get ']'.

```
for (int index = 0; index < cipher.length(); index = index + 1 ){

        char letter = cipher.charAt(index);

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letter)) {
            letter = (char) (((int) letter - 65 + shiftAmount) % 26 + 65);
        }
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(letter)) {
            letter = (char)(((int) letter - 97 + shiftAmount) % 26 + 97);
        }
        str.append(letter);
    }
```

You need to check the upper and lower characters and then add values accordingly.